# Ubuntu 17.10 in VMWare Fusion VM - Network Unavailable

Tags: networking, vmware, 17.10

When I launch my Ubuntu 17.10 VM, I see something to do with the network fail as it's booting up, and once it's booted, there is no internet connection. The host connection is running fine, and I have VMWare Fusion set to share this connection.

This randomly happened in the last couple times of booting it up. It was working just fine after my initial upgrade of the VM to 17.10,

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.